# How to add image from assets folder

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

to add image from src/asset folder

when I put the image directly to src folder, the react bootstrap image function worked. now I want to call it from a folder (storing all images) src/assests/LearningCount.png

import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image'
import LearningCount from './assets/LearningCount.png';

Error in ./src/components/SignIn/index.js
Module not found: ./assets/LearningCount.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse back into the asset folder, using ..
Given the error, try using '../../assets/LearningCount.png'

Answer (score -1):

Instead of import from './**assets**/LearningCount.png', you should import from 'src/**assests**/LearningCount.png', that's how you named your folder.